# Qt/SQL - Get column type and name from QSqlQuery exec Stored Procedure?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qt5, qsqlquery

I've connected to MSSQL server using QSqlDatabase class. Then I can get stored procedures' results with QSQLQuery like:

```
QSqlQuery q;
q.prepare ("EXEC TestStoredProcedure");
if (q.exec ()) { 
    while (q.next ()) {
        qDebug() << q.value (0).toString ();
        ...
    }
}
```

So, I have values of the returned fields, but **how I can get fields' names and types?** Stored procedure can form the list of returned fields dynamically.

Thanks for any help and answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use QSqlRecord. 
For example:

```
QSqlRecord localRecord = q.record();
for (int var = 0; var < localRecord.count(); ++var) {
    QString fieldName = localRecord.fieldName(var);
    qDebug() << fieldName;
}
```

or

```
QSqlRecord localRecord = q.driver()->record("table");
for (int var = 0; var < localRecord.count(); ++var) {
    QString fieldName = localRecord.fieldName(var);
    qDebug() << fieldName;
}
```

I think you can work without column type.

Comment: Thank you! First example is what i needed! The second one with table - I've tried yet but I've missed that I can get QSqlRecord From QSqlQuery) Also I can get type with: localRecord.field(var).type() .